# How to select a cell with a spesific condition in Excel with COUNTIF formula?

Tags: excel

I have a table named "Table1". I want to count spesific cells in it's first column named "Type". I have a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[Type]; I2)
```

That counts all values equals to string in I2. But I want to count the cells equal to I2 and with cell style "Good". (Or with cell color like "light green" would be fine as well.)
I have tried this:

```
=COUNTIF(Table1[Type]; AND(I2;CELL("color")="light green")))
```

But it doesn't work. And there is no an attribute like "style" in "CELL".

Does anyone know how can I achieve that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to use VBA to do it. Refer to this link for details:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/12/count-sum-by-color-excel/